# Knowing At what point the application freezes

Tags: c#

I am developing a WinForm multithreaded application with C#.
Sometimes it happens that my application hangs, or freezes or blocks.

When this happens and I am running in DEBUG mode, is there anyway to understand at what line of code my application is currently? Since it is freezed I expect to find a point where the application is locked or blocked or whatever. 
Is it possible to do that someway?

When It is freezed I tried to open the CALL STACK window, but this doesn't display any info; is there some action that I might do? Some "pause and check" or whatever?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may need to open the Threads window, and change the current thread.  While debugging, choose Debug->Break All, and open the Threads window.  If you go through each thread, by double clicking on the thread, you should be able to investigate the call stack for each thread.

That being said, if you can run your program in VS 2010 - this gets a lot easier.  In VS 2010, you can use the new Concurrency Profiler, and run your code under the Concurrency Profiler with the option to Visualize the Behavior of a multithreaded application.  Once your application locks up, kill it, and let the profiler churn -

Eventually, you'll get a diagram which shows each thread in your program, and when they're locked.  The callstack for each blocked thread will be shown, as well as what lock is being held (with the line of source code).  This makes it very easy to track down a dead lock.

Comment: Hi Reed! Thank you very much for your great response! One more small thing if you are still around..I don't have VS 2010 and I am still using VS 2008. Do you know whether there is some good free tool producing  more or less the same thing you just described for thread diagrams? Thanks for your help.

Comment: No - I don't know of anything free that's at all close.  Intel's threading toolkit works (but is very expensive).  You can download VS 2010 RC Ultimate for free right now, and run it on your projects, though...

Answer (score 2):

When debugger is attached go to Debug menu and choose 'Break All'... Then you can examine call stacks for all thread.

Answer (score 2):

You could press pause and see where it ends up (use the aforementioned call stack window). Chances are however that you'll end up in native code. You could try to step out a bit or just look at the stack for a managed function to debug.

Alternatively you could put a breakpoint after the application "freezes" and try to pinpoint a loop that doesn't end.

Both the above are assuming your application is busy (100% cpu usage). If your application is however stuck in a dead lock or just plain waiting for a mutex that won't tick, you'll have to manually re-read your code and try to figure it out on your own.

Comment: Auch! Really? Manually read the code is the only way to figure out where do I have a deadlock? Times ago I read about a powerful tool called WinDbg. Have you ever used and do you know if that table is able to help me in detecting at which piece of code the application is stucked_

Comment: Well if you're in a deadlock, your thread is stuck in a function somewhere deep in the rtl dll until the condition is determined to be satisfied by the scheduler. A call stack won't tell you what condition is being waited on.